# Appcelerator Build Code Signing error Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, appcelerator, ios10

I have been working on a app and worked fine on xcode 7.3 - but after upgrade to version 8.0 I got this error

**Error details: Provisioning profile "IOS_Dis_AppStore" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Developer: NAME (********)".

Error details: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'**

I use Appcelerator CLI 5.5.0

I think is released to the setting (from https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/08/release-candidate-for-titanium-sdk-5-5-0-and-appcelerator-cli-5-5-0)

```
<ios>
 <team-id>YOUR-TEAM-ID</team-id>
 <!-- more iOS specific keys -->
</ios>
```

But not sure where to put it in the tiapp.xml file
I have this in tiapp.xml

```
<ios>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
            <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
        </dict>
    </plist
```

I have tried to create new profile and certificate - but not working
HELP HELP
--/ T

Answer (score 2):

It goes outside of the plist element.

```
<ios>
    <team-id>YOUR-TEAM-ID</team-id>
    <plist>
        <!-- Your Info.plist keys go inside here -->
    </plist>
</ios>
```

Comment: Stephen, what is the YOUR-TEAM-ID ?

Comment: Team ID comes from Apple.  You can find it by logging into your apple account, visit the account summary, and the Team ID will be listed there.